# Can std::thread/jthread exit without executing passed function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, language-lawyer, c++20

Is it possible that joining `std::thread` or `std::jthread` too quickly (before the thread can actually be started in OS) cause the thread to not execute at all? Or is it guaranteed that it will simply block the parent thread until the child thread starts, executes and finishes?

I thought it's quite obvious that it should execute, but my colleague said it doesn't have to happen if `std::stop_source` is already triggered on jthread before the callback is called, hence my confusion.

Example:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void foo()
{
    std::cout << "foo()" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::jthread{foo};
    std::thread{foo}.join();
}
```

This outputs:

```
foo()
foo()
```

ThreadSanitizer doesn't report issues either, but I'd like to have some confirmation from standard.

Comment: I would expect `int main() { std::thread t{foo}; }`  to terminate right away. Why not?

Comment: oh sorry, I missed that the quesiton is about joining. But then I dont understand the part of the quesiton that refers to `std::thread`. How would you `join` a `thread` without executing the passed function?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I think what I'm really asking is this: is there a race condition between starting a thread (calling `foo` in new thread) and joining it (from main thread)? Is it ever possible to have a different output on the above code or is it safe to assume that `foo` will be called twice no matter what?

Comment: With std::thread it is possible that foo will never be called. What I do for (critical) thread functions is to set a variable/condition variable on foo's entry. And I wait on the calling thread for this variable to be set. Due to OS scheduling you cannot be sure the function has really started after creating the thread. This is regardless of calling join

Comment: still not sure if I understand but probably thats due to wrong assumption i have made till now ;)

Comment: @PepijnKramer afaict only if copying `foo` or it's arguments throws can it not *start*

Comment: @Caleth I have seen very rare occurences where my thread function is not called yet/started right after the creation of the thread class returns.  It looks like the thread was created but not scheduled by OS yet. (Windows + msvc)

Comment: @PepijnKramer yes, but that doesn't mean `join`ing the thread will never schedule it

Comment: @Caleth that's what I tried to say with "regarless of join". I also found cppreference is not clear enough on this. But luckily you found the link to the standard :)

Answer (score 5):

The constructor ensures and synchronises with the invocation of the passed function

> *Effects*: The new thread of execution executes
> `invoke(auto(std::forward<F>(f)), auto(std::forward<Args>(args))...)`
> with the values produced by auto being materialized ([conv.rval]) in the constructing thread. Any return value from this invocation is ignored.
>
> *Synchronization*: The completion of the invocation of the constructor synchronizes with the beginning of the invocation of the copy of `f`.

[`[thread.thread.constr]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.constr#6)

The join synchronises with the end of the thread

> *Synchronization*: The completion of the thread represented by `*this` synchronizes with ([intro.multithread]) the corresponding successful `join()` return.

[`[thread.thread.member]`](https://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.class#thread.thread.member-4)

Similar wording is present for `jthread`, except that it might pass it's `stop_token` to `f`

Signalling a `stop_source` doesn't stop a `jthread`, it is up to the invoked code to inspect the `stop_token` and finish.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OP asks for both, the wording is the same